# Installable ISAM Error when trying to use DoCmd.TransferDatabase to link a table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use DoCmd.TransferDatabase to link a SQL Server Express table to an Access 2013 table. I have no problems with other program code that accesses  table data in SQL Server and Access.

The error message that I am getting is: "could not find installable ISAM".
I have had no success in running Microsoft's DoCmd.TransferDatabase sample programs or in finding an answer on the Web to the ISAM problem.

The code is as follows:

```
Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With AccessConn

  .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
  '.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
  .Properties("Data Source").Value = TempVars!GlobalServerName
  .Properties("User ID").Value = "sa"
  .Properties("Password").Value = "xxxxxx"
  .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = TempVars!GlobalDatabaseName
  .Open

End With



DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
"[ODBC;DSN={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXS1\SQLExpress;Database=ADatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;]" _
& "DATABASE=D:\DatabaseDirectory\DatabaseTables.accdb", acTable, "Table1", "Table1;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, play with connection string, this worked for me.

"ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=MyServerName;DATABASE=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PrintFormPB_Click()

'The purpose of this code is to be able to print Access Reports when the data are stored in
'a SQL Server database. One way to do this is to link all the SQL Tables to all the Access
'tables, but this has multiple disadvantages including the fact that the linker duplicates
'all of the SQL Table data in Access.
'This program only transfers Table data when it is required by Access Reports. The table
'data can then be deleted.
'There are several Report options. You can print the current Form page or all of the pages
'using a Report template. It is also possible to set a variety of printer options.

'This code links a SQL Server Table to an Access Table. The link command creates a new table
'that is named by appending a suffix the Table name. For example, Table allergies is linked
'as Allergies1. It is preferable to link to the original Table name, but the linker
'apparently cannot do this.

'This is part of an Open Source personal "MedicalRecords" program.

Dim strSQL As String
Dim database_path As String
Dim oRpt As Report
Dim AccessConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim MsgBoxResponse As Integer
Dim ret As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Setup the Access database connections

Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With AccessConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
        '.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source").Value = "D:\MedicalRecordsSQL\MedicalRecordTables.accdb"
    .Open
End With

'The following links a SQL Server Table called Allergies to an Access Table called Allergies1.
'The Access table Allergies is then deleted and Allergies1 is renamed to Allergies.
'These are undesirable steps, but no alternative is known at this time.
'Note the formats of the SQL Server statements.

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
"ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=RERS1\SQLExpress;UID=sa;PWD=<your Password>;DATABASE=MedicalRecordsSQL;;Table=dbo.Allergies;" _
& "DATABASE=|D:\MedicalRecordsSQL\|MedicalRecordTables.accdb", acTable, "dbo.Allergies", "Allergies"
Set AccessConn = Nothing
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Allergies"
DoCmd.Rename "Allergies", acTable, "Allergies1"

'Setup Report

DoCmd.OpenReport "Allergies", acViewDesign, Null, Null, acHidden

Set oRpt = Reports(0)
oRpt.UseDefaultPrinter = True
'oRpt.Printer = Application.Printers("printer name")

'Set printer options

With oRpt.Printer
        .PaperBin = acPRBNAuto
    .PaperSize = acPRPSLetter
    .Copies = 1
    .PrintQuality = acPRPQMedium
    .Orientation = acPRORLandscape
End With

'Print the report
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Allergies", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenReport "Allergies", acViewNormal, , "[ID] = " & Me.ID

Set oRpt = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBoxReturn = MsgBox("Error Source: Allergies_Form" & vbCrLf & "Error Line: " & Erl & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "")

End Sub
```